# clustered quartz instances schedule duplicate jobs?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, load-balancing

I have a Tomcat web application A that schedules jobs with quartz framework. It was running as one instance on RAM Jobstore. Recently we plan to move to JDBC Jobstore and set up a cluster, so that if one instance fails, the other instance will be able to run the job.

Here is my issues:

My we application A will scan a business related database table and schedule quartz jobs during starting up and every 10 minutes afterwards. If I deploy two A applications on two different tomcat instances, then there will be two sets of duplicate jobs scheduled through Quartz.

How should I solve this problem? Do I need to extract the part of code that schedules jobs into a separate application and make sure only 1 instance is deployed so only 1 sets of jobs are scheduled? But then the problem becomes - what if this instance fails? How do I achieve fail over in this case?

Comment: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering ?

Comment: The tag [tag:clustering] refers to the data mining problem. You question is about load balancing of web servers.

Comment: if your quartz is in clustered mode, then there will be no duplication of jobs. Only one instance will take the responsibility of executing it. So you can have multiple instances of your application given that it is in clustered mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the task "scan a business related database table and schedule quartz jobs during starting up and every 10 minutes afterwards" itself a cron task in the clustered quartz instance.

Following is a spring based solution. Though you can use the idea to convert to non-spring based solution easily.

set up a cron trigger for every ten minutes.

```
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 */10 * * * ?" />
</bean>
```

set up a Job. Here you will require a class instance in spring context.This class instance will have a public method which will invoked when trigger is fired. Within this method you will be writing the task to scan database and schedule these jobs.

```
<bean id="cronJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="yourObject" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="methodOfThatObject" />     
</bean>
```

Configure trigger and job in the scheduler

```
<!--this should be your clustered quartz scheduler-->
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronJob" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
        <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: But then you will have multiple instances in the same cluster and they will try to schedule duplicate jobs, right? How do I ensure only one instance is doing the scheduling inside multiple nodes? Thanks!

Comment: Clustered quartz scheduler setup is required when we want multiple instances of quartz and coordination between them so that only one instance executes the job.
If you are scheduling jobs through a cron, then this cron scheduling task itself can be added as a job in this clustered scheduler. Say every ten minutes you need to scan some datastore(eg mysql) and schedule jobs. In this case, say suppose there are 4 nodes in the cluster, only one instance will be executing this scheduling cron task. And similarly the job execution can happen in any of the nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Thank you very much Prem! Previously I did not realize that the job scheduling task will be picked up by only one instance, just like the jobs themselves. This is only true when it is pre configured, right? In other words, if I programmatically call scheduler.scheduleJob, then this call will be run by multiple nodes, right?

Comment: i havent tried this scenario. but I think programmatically there wont be any problem because even though we are configuring these jobs through xml the framework actually does them programmatically. You may want to test and ensure if you want it programmatically done.